# Streets or Street?

Tags: grammatical-number

When writing and address as the corner of two streets, do I use singular or plural for "street"? As an example, should it be "the corner of Grafton and Spence Street", or "the corner of Grafton and Spence Streets"?

Comment: Hi, Sandy, and welcome to ELU. You can just say "the corner of Grafton and Spence", or use *Streets*; *Street* would be used if only one was *street*, e.g. if the other was *Avenue*. You might be interested in our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is helpful in answering basic questions.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule of thumb is that you say enough to make the location clear and unambiguous to the listener or reader, while keeping the location description as short as possible.

- The listener is from out of town and doesn't know the area at all. The speaker would say "the corner of Grafton Street and Spence Street" or "the corner of Grafton and Spence Streets".
- The listener is familiar with the major streets in the area, but doesn't know the local streets well: "the corner of Grafton and Spence Street".
- If the listener is vaguely familiar with the area, but multiple similarly-named streets intersect with the major street (for instance, both Spence Street and Spence Drive): "the corner of Grafton and Spence Street" or "the corner of Grafton and Spence Drive".
- If the listener is as familiar with the area as the speaker, often both will be dropped as long as the result is not ambiguous: "the corner of Grafton and Spence".
- If both are familiar with the area, sometimes a qualifier other than the street type (Avenue, Drive, Circle, etc.) will be used to disambiguate. If, for instance, both know that there's no Starbucks on Spence Drive but there is one on Spence Street: "the corner of Grafton and Spence by the Starbucks".

This is why you'll hear locals in Silicon Valley saying things like, "I'll meet you on University across from the Apple Store" instead of "at the corner of University Avenue and Florence Street in Palo Alto" because there's only one University Avenue that has an Apple Store.

To emphasize how much this is dependent on context and assumed knowledge of the listener, "at California and El Camino" means "the corner of California Avenue and El Camino Real in Palo Alto" to someone from Palo Alto; to someone from Mountain View, it's meaningless, and you'd need to say the whole thing, because California Avenue in Mountain View never intersects El Camino Real at all!

Answer (score 0):

> should it be "the corner of Grafton and Spence Street", or "the corner of Grafton and Spence Streets"?

The second case is correct, however the first case must be written:

> the corner of Grafton Street and Spence Street

Then they are both correct and equivalent. Of course, if one of them was a Road and not a Street, then you would be forced to use the first form.

Comment: I'm not familiar with US conventions in this area, but I'd certainly not discount Joe's second bulleted example above. Deletions lead to all sorts of strange-looking grammar. And in Oxford, one might speak of the corner of the Turl [Turl Street] and Market Street.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth of course if a street is so well known and notable that it can be referred to without the suffix, then it may pass (the street/road whatever is implied). This is somewhat a special case though.

Comment: Joe deals with the special cases. Your answer doesn't improve on his at all.